# Get highest ids in by an inner join and max id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I got two tables, conversations and messages,
What I'd like to do is to make a inner join from conversations to messages.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT 
    messages.msg,
    messages.`read`,
    conversations.userid,
    conversations.contactid

    FROM conversations 
        INNER JOIN messages ON 
        conversations.id = messages.convId
    WHERE conversations.id IN(443,444)
```

Now everything works as it should, but a last thing is that in the inner join where i use

```
conversations.id = messages.convId
```

I would like to get the highest ids only, like:

```
 AND MAX(messages.id)
```

But that doesn't work

**EDIT:**
I tried once to use:

```
LEFT JOIN messages 
    ON conversations.id = messages.convId 
        AND messages.id = MAX(messages.id)
```

But i got an error saying: Invalid use of group function.

Comment: You can order your messages by id : ORDER BY conversations.id ASC, messages.id DESC

Comment: that will give me only one row, i'd like a row per convId

Comment: No, it will give multiple rows. But my mistake, I should have written ORDER BY conversations.id ASC, messages.id DESC GROUP BY conversations.id

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**EDIT**

This will work!

```
SELECT conversations.*, m1.* 
FROM conversations 
LEFT JOIN messages m1
    ON conversations.id = m1.cid 
    AND m1.id = (
            SELECT MAX(m2.id) 
            FROM messages m2 
            WHERE m2.cid = conversations.id
        )
```

Comment: actually this will not work, cuz it limits to only 1 row, i  want a row per conversations.id where it is the highest id in messags.convId

Comment: So you only want to retrieve the latest message for each conversation?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have used the `MAX()` function, and changed it from an INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, so your conversations are returned, even if there aren't any messages. `AND MAX(messages.id)` on its own won't work, however it should work if you compare it to the `messages.id` field: `AND messages.id = MAX(messages.id)`

Comment: i tried this too but getting an error which says: Invalid use of group function

Comment: I've updated the answer (again!) I've created a test database on my own server and tested the answer, and it works for me.

Comment: thanks a lot works perfect, brilliant job! another question, where did you learn mysql to this level? know any good tutorials?

Comment: Just a lot of trial and error, and googling! Stackoverflow also helps a lot ;-) although I would Definately not consider myself an sql expert.

Comment: +1 INNER JOIN might be better instead of LEFT JOIN though, depending on what @Kilise needs

Comment: @chue the only reason I used a left join is to display the conversations even if there isn't any comments :-)

Comment: @PhilCross - that is completely legitimate, assuming that is what Kilise wants.

Comment: @Phill what is the difference on using inner join instead of left join?

Comment: An inner join will only return conversations and messages of the is at least one message for the conversation.  A left join will return all the requested conversations, even if there isn't any messages for them. A right join would return all the messages even if there aren't any conversations for them.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the maximum value in a group.  MySQL does not have any really obvious way to do this (lots of ways with a bit of trickery).

But, you are only looking for two groups.  As such, you can just look for the limit in each group and combine them using `union all`:

```
SELECT m.msg, m.`read`, c.userid,
       c.contactid
FROM conversations c inner join
     ((select m.*
       from messages m
       where m.convid = 443
       order by m.id desc
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select m.*
       from messages m
       where m.convid = 444
       order by m.id desc
       limit 1
      )
     ) m
     ON c.id = m.convId;
```

If you have indexes on `messages(convid, id)` and `conversations(id)`, then this should be quite fast.

You can also do this using a more standard approach:

```
SELECT m.msg, m.`read`, c.userid,
       c.contactid
FROM conversations c inner join
     messages m
     ON c.id = m.convId
where c.convId in (443, 444) and
      m.id = (select max(id) from messages m2 where m2.convId = c.convId)
```

Answer (score 1):

the top solution above will not work everywhere, for example postgres will give errors, a better solution to join tables and only get the max id from the other table:

```
SELECT conversations.*, m.* 
    FROM conversations 
    JOIN (SELECT cid, max(id) as m_id from messages group by cid) as m
        ON conversations.id = m.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

The max ID is unique because there is no larger ID in the table. Obviously..

If you **left** join a table with itself, there is no row on the right side that has a higher ID than the max ID but for any other row there is at least one that has a higher ID (the row with the max id).

For only the entry with the max ID in table1, no entry in table2 can meet the condition:
`table1.id < table2.id`.

So with the condition in the join, we can filter for the row with the max ID using :
`table2.id is null`.

```
SELECT table1.id
FROM t table1
LEFT JOIN t table2 on table1.id < table2.id
WHERE table2.id is null
```

or in the example provided in the question:

```
SELECT 
    messages.msg,
    messages.`read`,
    conversations.userid,
    conversations.contactid

FROM conversations 
INNER JOIN messages ON conversations.id = messages.convId 
LEFT JOIN _messages ON 
        messages.convId = _messages.convId and 
        messages.convId < _messages.convId
WHERE 
    _messages.convID is null and
    conversations.id IN(443,444)
```